# Stripe SCA checkout in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am trying to update a monolithic rails stripe form to be SCA complaint, this is the documentation I am following https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration#api-products-after[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pyq2.png)
but is give in me error, invalid parameter, the error is in the picture, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EblVb.png)

this is my code

```
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_BqQVTnHd7yKaGgzUK9q8m8Ub00');
  let checkoutButton = document.querySelector('#checkout-button');
  checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      items: [{
        // Define the product and SKU in the Dashboard first, and use the SKU
        name: 'onex',
        // ID in your client-side code.
        id: 1,
        parent: 'sku_Ft94t7sJmbJHlY',
        sku: 'sku_123',
        quantity: 1
      }],
      successUrl: 'https://www.example.com/success',
      cancelUrl: 'https://www.example.com/cancel'
    });
  });
```

and I created a product in stripe dashboard

```
enter code here
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oyb1s.png)

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: sorry, code add it!!

Answer (score 0):

According to Stripe's documentation, the only properties you can pass into the `items` list of `stripe.redirectToCheckout` are `sku`, `plan`, and `quantity`.

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-redirect-to-checkout

So in this case, the name, id, and parent properties are invalid. The "client-side" checkout integration is made to be pretty simplistic, where you create the SKU in the dashboard and simply include it in your JS.

If you need more control, I'd recommend looking at their server-side integration, which involves creating a Checkout Session.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server#create-checkout-session

Comment: I installed this stripe 3d secure with this tutorials https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/3d-secure-2-credit-cards-and-stripe-checkout-preview